# Left Join Drupal 7

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, left-join

I have this problem regarding Drupal 7 Mysql queries especially on LEFT JOIN.

I found this solution but I can't seem it apply it on my problem since I'm not aware how the syntax goes.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/how-do-i-write-a-left-join-query

This is the solution that I found on the link above.

```
$terms = db_select('taxonomy_index', 'ti')
  ->fields('ti', array('tid', 'name'))
  ->leftJoin('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd', 'ti.tid = ttd.tid')
  ->condition('vid', 2)
  ->condition('nid', $nid)
  ->execute();

foreach ($terms as $term) {
  // $term contains the object for the taxonomy term.
}
```

Yet I'm having a problem on how do I apply it to my query.

Here is my LEFT JOIN query on mysql.

```
$query = "SELECT sweep_table.end_offer, sweep_table.title, embed.fbp_id, embed.sweep_stat 
    FROM sweep_table, embed 
    WHERE sweep_table.uid=embed.uid AND sweep_table.promo_id=embed.sweep_id";
```

I already did the first few lines but the rest, I don't know how.

```
$terms = db_select('sweep_table', 'embed')
  ->fields('sweep_table', array('end_offer', 'title'))
  ->fields('embed', array('fbp_id', 'sweep_stat'))
  ->leftJoin('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd', 'ti.tid = ttd.tid') //Don't know how to apply to my query.
  ->condition('vid', 2)
  ->condition('nid', $nid)
  ->execute();

foreach ($terms as $term) {

}
```

Also, was wondering how do I retrieve the data after I successfully LEFT JOIN it?

Would be glad if you help me guys.

Comment: Why don't you simply execute the SQL statement instat of building it?

Comment: Does it work? 
I don't know if it does though, was wondering how do I retrieve the data?
This doesn't work though "echo $term->sweep_table->end_offer;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't have thought that this would work though. Thanks to rekire for the hint.

```
$query = "SELECT sweep_table.end_offer, sweep_table.title, embed.fbp_id, embed.sweep_stat FROM sweep_table, embed WHERE sweep_table.uid=embed.uid AND sweep_table.promo_id=embed.sweep_id";
$result = db_query($query);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row->end_offer . " " . $row->title . " " . $row->fbp_id . " " . $row->sweep_stat . "<br>";
}
```